# Apache Beam Dataflow Fixed Window without grouping

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having an issue with fixed windowing. I'm using fixed windows to write to a file every minute with the batched data.

The problem is that for whatever reason using this:

```
| "Window into Fixed Intervals"
  >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60),trigger=beam.trigger.AfterProcessingTime(1 * 60),
    accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
```

doesn't seem to do anything to actually window the data. I need to follow it up with a groupbykey to actually group the data into the time windows for some reason.

I do this by

```
                "Add Dummy Key" 
                >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (None, elem))
                | "Groupby" 
                >> beam.GroupByKey()
                | "Abandon Dummy Key" 
                >> beam.MapTuple(lambda _, val: val)
                | "Write to GCS" 
                >> beam.ParDo(WriteBatchesToGCS(output_path))
```

This adds 50x processing time to my pipeline. Is there a better way to do this or am I missing something?

Is dataflow even the right tool for this?

Comment: Do you mean that you write nothing to GCS if you don't put the group by by?

Comment: Nah, it just writes message by message to GCS which throws a ton of errors since it's trying to modify the same file for a minute.

Comment: why do you perform window if you don't count, aggregate, group by, or combine your message? A a global window with a periodic trigger is enough, isn't it?

Comment: hahaha thank you for reminding me i'm an idiot. you're right. I just set a periodic trigger for batching and that actually seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Stupid question can solve big issue!!! Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the windows need a GBK, see  https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing 8.1.1 Windowing constraints

> If you set a windowing function using the Window transform, each element is assigned to a window, but the windows are not considered until GroupByKey or Combine aggregates across a window and key

Comment: Damn. Well that sucks, no way to get around this requirement otherwise?

Comment: you can try using stateful dofn with batching and timers to achieve this, but it may not help. Try: https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/ - Look at the GroupIntoBatches transform - it may achieve something like what you want